# Flipping an image in java

Tags: java, image, for-loop, pixel, mirror

I'm trying to flip an image in java, but I ran into a problem that I just cannot figure out.

Using a double-for-loop, I'm running through all pixelvalues in the org image, and copying them to the new image in the pixel(width-x-1,y).

The following picture depicts, what happens when I run the method.

http://tinypic.com/r/nqzsiu/8

The new image, only seems to run through 1/10 of the image' height for some reason. Why is this and how do I fix it?

```
private Image img;
private Pixel pixel;
private Image newimg;
private Pixel newpixel;

public advancedFilters(Image img)
{
    this.img = img;
}

public Image Mirror(){
    newimg = new Image(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), "newimage");
    int curtone;
    for (int j=0; j<img.getHeight(); j++) {
        for (int i=0; i<img.getWidth(); i++) {
            pixel = img.getPixel(i,j);
            curtone = pixel.getValue();
            newpixel = newimg.getPixel(newimg.getWidth()-i-1, j);
            newpixel.setValue(curtone);

        }
    }
    return newimg;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `img.getHeight()` returns the correct height?

Comment: What is Image? It can't be java.awt.Image since it is using that constructor.

Comment: Its .jpg, and yeah - img.getHeight() returns the height as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you storing the temporary values `private Pixel pixel` and `private Pixel newpixel` outside of the scope where they're being used? This is unnecessary (from the code that you posted at least) and is asking for trouble. Try this implementation of your algorithm (which appears correct) instead:

```
private Image img;
private Pixel pixel;
private Image newimg;
private Pixel newpixel;

public advancedFilters(Image img)
{
    this.img = img;
}

public Image Mirror(){
    newimg = new Image(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), "newimage");
    for (int j=0; j<img.getHeight(); j++) {
        for (int i=0; i<img.getWidth(); i++) {
            Pixel oldPixel = img.getPixel(i,j);
            int oldPixelVal = oldPixel.getValue();
            Pixel mirrorPixel = newimg.getPixel((newimg.getWidth()-i-1), j);
            mirrorPixel.setValue(curtone);

        }
    }
    return newimg;
}
```

Comment: This didn't result in anything other than the same result. Could the problem lie within the Image class itself? I don't see it likely, seeing as, using the same algorithm for inverting the colors ex., results correctly.

Any other ideas, what might be causing this?

Comment: Alright so there's a few places we need to check. First, make sure that your `i` and `j` variables actually increment all the way to `img.getWidth()` and `img.getHeight()`. If they do, try writing the newimg out to a file and opening it yourself, the problem could be with how you are displaying the newimage in java.

Comment: Found the problem. Forgot to include a method I made for updating the image according to the changed pixels. Thanks for your help anyways though!

Answer (score 0):

This is not containing the complete question. You just need to call newImg.pixelsUpdated(); before you return it. But there is NO way StackOverflow users can know this.